# Designing a familiarity system

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to design a system of knowledge for the application. I have a user entity. I want the user to have a list of friends. There are two ways to do this.

The first way on the entities.. The user has a list

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "user_friends",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "to_user_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "from_user_id")}
)
private Set<FriendshipEntity> friends;
```

FriendshipEntity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users_friends")
public class FriendshipEntity {

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "from_user_id", nullable = false)
    private UserEntity fromUser;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "to_user_id", nullable = false)
    private UserEntity toUser;
}
```

I create friendship in this way

```
fromUser.getFriends().add(new FriendshipEntity(fromUser, toUser));
toUser.getFriends().add(new FriendshipEntity(toUser, fromUser));
```

The second way for the ID itself.

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(
        name = "users_friends",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
)
private Set<Long> friends;
```

Creating friendships

```
fromUser.getFriends().add(toUser.getId());
toUser.getFriends().add(fromUser.getId());
```

Which way in your opinion is the best to create a friendships system? Maybe you have another idea?

Comment: My other idea, which won't be popular with DBAs, is to compose User as a regular POJO object with a List<User> member field of friends, and then serialize it to a blob in the database.

Comment: Your first design is invalid. If Friendship has a ManyToOne with User, then the other side of the bidirectional association must be a OneToMany, not a ManyToMany. And it must be the inverse side, marked with the mappedBy attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the luxury to choose the data store, I'd suggest using a graph database instead. A graph database is much more suitable for this use case, a system where the emphasis is on relationships, than an SQL database. A graph database allows you to create more complex queries a lot more elegant and efficient than a SQL database ever could. For an example of a friends graph, please see [this link](https://neo4j.com/developer/cypher-query-language/) from Neo4j.

Your first approach is exactly the same as one who would implement it with [Spring Data Neo4j](https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-neo4j/), just with different annotations.